# Extracting datepart from a date field in R

Tags: r, datepart

So I have a date variable with data as `6/26/2016 0:00` and I want it to convert it as `6/26/2016`, How should I do it?

Comment: try `as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y")` to convert to Date class. Use `format` if needed

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

`original_date <- "6/26/2016 0:00"
new_date <- format(as.Date(original_date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")`